# Spring task:scheduler. What causes missed runs?

Tags: java, spring, job-scheduling

We have an application that has many batch jobs in it.  Something is making some of the batch runs "skip" a run.  So specifically we have one set like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */5 * * * *")
```

which is every 5 minutes.  So this specific job usually runs every 5 minutes but also skips runs.  The individual runs last less then 5 seconds so they are not stacking up.

We are using this to run them:

```
<task:annotation-driven />
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10" />
```

and probably have over 10 jobs.  Is the "pool-size" possibly messing us up?  I can't find any docs on the web on what setting would be good for this.  We are using Spring 3.x

NEW INFO:  Adding pools to the pool size does not help.  Also, we have some jobs that are suppose to run every 5 minutes on the 5 and seem to run at random times after the 5.

NEW INFO:  Added this and it seemed to help some, but not completely. Still having the problem.

```
<task:annotation-driven scheduler="taskScheduler" executor="taskExecutor" />
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="20" />
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="20" />
```

Comment: Seems like if you have more jobs than you have threads to run them it's possible some of the jobs would be missed/deferred. What happens if you increase the pool-size to something equal to or greater than the number of jobs you are running?

Comment: It's strange enough.  Spring scheduler must have an orchestration class for managing jobs executions. So if i am right, it should check "SimpleThreadPool" for available "worker" (thread). If all "workers" are busy at the moment, orchestration should wait until any "worker" can satisfy a waiting job in a queue (technically to start a run() method for specific job). So according to this, there shouldn't occur any skips.

Comment: 00Enthusiast, that is exactly how I thought it would work.  I am testing to see if increasing the threads will help.  I would expect there to be some kind of logging on this, though...

Comment: @markthegrea, were you able to solve this by increasing the thread-pool for scheduler ?